# I want to switch the pages in Navigation bar dynamically in django, But my error is page not found 404

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

**Homepage.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}"></a>
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request,'test_homepage.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home,name="home"),
]
```

Comment: page is test_homepage.html

Comment: I do not really follow what the problem is?

Comment: I just want to switch the HTML pages in navigation bar in Django

Comment: But to what? It looks like you want to redirect from `home` to, well..., `home` right now. Usually if you want to perform a redirect, it is to somewhere else.

Comment: suppose from this homepage.html I want to switch to different HTML page in navigation bar